# How to build a control like XamTilesControl of Infragistics in WPF?

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls, infragistics

I have been recently using infragistics controls in my project. In that XamTilesControl is amazing. Its give a more flexible layout and rearrangement of panels. Any idea how to create a custom control to get this behaviour?

Comment: If the XamTilesControl already meets your needs is there a reason that you don't use it?  It is already a custom control that has the behavior, why recreate something that exists?

Comment: The control is simply amazing. That's why I am curious to know how this could be done with basic WPF Elements.

Comment: If you purchase the Infragistics toolset, it comes with the source code and you could look at that.